# How to get Disk Stats based on different parameters

Tags: iostat

Is there any way to get a disk stats grouped on certain params like:

writes by size/latency?
reads by size/latency?

something like:

```
total writes - 100
writes by size:
    - < 4096 - 20
    - 4096 - 16384 - 30
    ...
```

Where 4096/16384 being the chunk size.

Answer (score 1):

Group by latency with eBPF: https://github.com/iovisor/bcc/blob/v0.9.0/tools/biolatency_example.txt

I don't know about grouping by size.  It should definitely be possible, either using eBPF, or blktrace.  (I think `blktrace` has slightly higher overheads).

---

Confusingly, `block/blk-stat.c` implements some sort of latency histogram.  (See references to "bucket"s.  However, it is only used in a couple of places inside the kernel: there is no way to use this from outside the kernel.